# SEO for one page site

Tags: web, seo

I am going to create a new website and I am thinking to make the whole website as one page like 
http://www.demdous.com/examples/html/laboratory/2/

 so is that will be a problem with Search Engine Optimization ? 
Is it preferably to make the website multiple page instead of one page or it make no sense ?
 In the future google will be able to divide it like
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should read through this documentation and make sure you can accommodate google's ajax requirements before you get start. If you can't, you may want to consider pages that make round trip requests to the server.
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

I'd question why you want to make it a single page site like the example you provided.

Is it a stylistic choice? A matter of simplicity? That said, SEO will still largely be about the content of your site, quality links back to your site, and your social media presence.

As long as you're paying attention to these factors (as well as technical concerns like optimizing for HTML5 and Ajax) you should be fine.